# HTML сноска в Android

Tags: java, android, html

Приветствую.

Я пишу андроид приложение, мои текстовые данные хранятся в БД, они там обработаны HTML тегами, получив эти данные в своем приложении я загружаю их в `textview` следующим образом:

```
  question_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(QUESTION_TEXT));
```

Все работает, однако, у меня появилась нужда вставить внутри текста сноску, в HTML она ставится так:

```
   <sup><acronym title="Текст сноски">[1]</acronym></sup>
```

Я прописал этот код в тексте в БД, и сноска отобразилась, но при наведении или клике на нее ничего не происходит. Вопрос: Как правильно прописать код сноски в БД, чтобы андроид приложение корректно отобразило эту сноску? Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Средствами из коробки, это, думаю, невозможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот способ предоставляет очень ограниченную поддержку HTML.
Для полноценной нужно использовать WebView, это движок из встроенного браузера, там можно включить JavaScript, и с помощью JS и CSS реализовать любой функционал, только не забыть хорошо протестировать на минимальной и максимальной из поддерживаемых версий ОС, особенно если этот диапазон проходит через 4.4, где движок WebKit заменили на Chromium.

Comment: Получается что я могу создать отдельную директорию, поместить туда, например, файлы html, css, js, связаные между собой, и указать на главный `index` файл, и веб вью просто отобразит это все? Или альтернативный способ, это указать простую `Url` ссылку?

Comment: @McDaggen Можно вообще без файлов, просто HTML из string, в нем можно inline CSS и inline JS.

Comment: Ясность полная!